# generating rdf from sparql endpoint using ARC2 in php

Tags: php, rdf, store, sparql

i am having sparql store and I would like to know how to generate rdf file from sparql store using ARC2 in php.

I tried with sparql store dump(), but it returns back as xml. Any parser which I can use to convert this xml to rdf will help.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the dumped XML?  It is highly likely that this is RDF/XML which is RDF

Comment: <sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">

  <results>

    <result>

      <binding name="s">

        <uri>http://abc.com/onto#c_4da6b71ea3489</uri>

      </binding>

      <binding name="p">

        <uri>http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type</uri>

      </binding>

      <binding name="o">

        <uri>http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept</uri>

      </binding>

      <binding name="g">

        <uri>http://abc.com/rdfgraph</uri>

      </binding>

    </result>

    <result>

    ....

    </result>

</sparql>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the output you are getting is a SPARQL XML Results which is a SPOG dump (i.e. Quads based) of the Store.

You should be able to convert this into Triples and then serialize these as RDF yourself but it will require a bit of coding.

I don't know PHP or ARC2 well so I would suggest looking through the documentation at https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki or asking on their mailing list at http://groups.google.com/group/arc-dev

Answer (score 0):

To generate RDF from SPARQL you use a CONSTRUCT query.

A normal SELECT looks like this: (I am skipping the PREFIX bits)

```
SELECT ?person ?email 
 WHERE { ?person a foaf:Person . ?person foaf:mbox ?email }
```

And that reutrns the XML you are seeing. You want something like:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?person a foaf:Person . ?person foaf:mbox ?email }
 WHERE { ?person a foaf:Person . ?person foaf:mbox ?email }
```

Which will create a graph of triples from the results in the WHERE. You can even use it to create triples that were not in the endpoint, but are based on the same data.